# how to get value from xml by Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

i was reading huge xml file of 5GB size by using the following code, and i was success to get the first element `Testid`  but failed to get another element `TestMin` coming under different namespace
this is the xml i am having

```
 which i am getting as null
```

.What is wrong here?

**EDIT**
GMileys answer giving error like `The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually namespace was the culprit,what i did is first loaded the small section i am getting from.Readform method in to xdocument,then i removed all the namespace,then i took the value .simple :)

Answer (score 3):

The element `es:qRxLevMin` is a child element of `xn:attributes`, but it looks like you are trying to select it as a child of `xn:vsDataContainer`, it is a grandchild of that element. You could try changing the following:

```
var dataqrxlevmin = from atts in pin.ElementsAfterSelf(xn + "VsDataContainer")
        select new
        {
            qrxlevmin = (string)atts.Element(es + "qRxLevMin"),
        };
```

To this:

```
var dataqrxlevmin = from atts in pin.Elements(string.Format("{0}VsDataContainer/{1}attributes", xn, es))
        select new
        {
            qrxlevmin = (string)atts.Element(es + "qRxLevMin"),
        };
```

Note: I changed your string concatenation to use `string.Format` for readability purposes, either is technically fine to use, but `string.Format` is a better approach.

Comment: Getting exception like The : charactor hexadecimal value ,cannot be included in name

Comment: Where are you getting that exception? Try writing out or adding a watch to your variables. Set a local variable to use instead of passing it in-line: `string elementPath = string.Format("{0}:VsDataContainer/{1}:attributes", xn, es);` The `Console.WriteLine(elementPath);` and `var dataqrxlevmin = from atts in pin.Elements(elementPath) ...`. Do that with each of your path strings to ensure you are using the correct XPath.

Comment: If you could, add a section to your question with some of the stuff we have tried here. Have a section called "debug information" and add the code you have updated as we discussed here along with the output of of the debug statements: `Console.WriteLine(elementPath);`, etc...

Comment: it seems string.format is the culprit ,we cant use : in expression rather +

Comment: Ah, you just need to escape the colon. Try using `\:` instead of just `:`. I had completely forgot that a colon needed to be escaped. My bad. =)

Comment: Could you update your question in the way I was suggesting? Don't replace or delete your existing, original question, just append the new, updated/modified code including the runtime values that get assigned to those variables. That way we can see what we are working with. Thanks,

Comment: error is The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer. I wasn't thinking about it at the time apparently. I believe that when the Namespace is converted to a string the colon may be added as necessary as part of the implicit `ToString` call. I have updated my answer to get rid of the extra colons. You should be all set now.

Comment: Now new error the character /  hexadecimal value 0*2F cannot be included in a name

Comment: You should keep your original question in there, when I asked that you include some of the discussions, I also mentioned that you should keep your original question in place. Without your original question a lot of this is lost on anyone looking to solve a similar problem.

Comment: i think u misinterpreted with XPath and Xname,actually namespace was the culprit,what i did is first loaded the small section i am getting from.Readform method in to xdocument,then i removed all the namespace,then i took the value .simple :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

XName utranCellName = XName.Get("UtranCell", "un");
XName qRxLevMinName = XName.Get("qRxLevMin", "es");

var cells = doc.Descendants(utranCellName);

foreach (var cell in cells)
{
    string qRxLevMin = cell.Descendants(qRxLevMinName).FirstOrDefault();

    // Do something with the value
}
```

Comment: 5GB file, i will get a memory out of exception

Answer (score 1):

try this code which is very similar to your code but simpler.

```
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path))
            {
                 xr.MoveToContent();
                 XNamespace un = xr.LookupNamespace("un");
                 XNamespace xn = xr.LookupNamespace("xn");
                 XNamespace es = xr.LookupNamespace("es");
                 while (!xr.EOF)
                 {
                     if(xr.LocalName != "UtranCell")
                     {
                         xr.ReadToFollowing("UtranCell", un.NamespaceName);
                     }
                     if(!xr.EOF)
                     {
                         XElement utranCell = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xr);
                     }
                }
            }
```